# Drupal 6: Use a view to display data in a vertical HTML table

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

Iniside a view, I have a relationship set up between two tables: departments and employees.
I want to use a view to display it in the following format:

```
Department A | Department B | Department C
 Employee 1      Employee 5     Employee 6
 Employee 2      Employee 7     Employee 8
 Employee 3
 Employee 4
```

But until now, using the grid and table style, I'm only able to display it as follow:

```
Department A 
 Employee 1   
 Employee 2   
 Employee 3
 Employee 4

Department B
 Employee 5  
 Employee 7

Department C
 Employee 6  
 Employee 8
```

I know I could create a module or a block for this but I would prefer to leave it inside a view and enable our client to change it whenever he wants to. How would you solve this requirement?  Is there a view hook that would allow me to access the data and wrap my HTML table around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by making it "a view in a view". The basic view is a view of departments, set to display in a grid, with 3 grids per page. It will have 2 fields - department title field, and a field containing the view of employees. How do you put a view as a field? I suggest you use the [Views Customfield](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield) module set to PHP and calling the list of employees with `views_embed_view($name, $display_id)`.